# Why fan gets enabled again and again after thinkfan started and ended once?

Tags: linux, thinkpad, fan

I used to manually disable fan writing "level 0" to `/proc/acpi/ibm/fan` and fan stayed off. Recently I installed `thinkfan`, started it, then stopped, but manual disabling it stopped working after such actions. Why? What could have changed in the system to result in such change for the fan?

System restart reverses it back - `echo level 0 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan` works again, running and stopping thinkfan (even when fan has not started during run) messes up with writing to `/proc/acpi/ibm/fan` as before, modification time of `/proc/acpi/ibm/fan` stays with time of manual write, but output changes to "enabled".

Below is a reproducible example (at least for my downloaded Linux Mint 20.2. and my Thinkpad; I initially discovered it on another Thinkpad model). For some as of now non-understandable reason, thinkfan on liveUSB does not use systemd, but the result is the same: the fan starts in absence of the thinkfan process after being manually disabled; thinkfan is same version, 0.9.1 (as output from `thinkfan -h`).

- I've made USB with Linux Mint 20.2.
- I'm booting it with "persistent" flag on the `vmlinuz` line instead of   "quiet splash"
- I've run `echo options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf` then rebooted
- After reboot, I'm able to manually set fan speed by `echo level 0 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan`
- I've installed `apt-get install stress`
- Fan speed remains 0 (as for noise and `cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan`) when I do `stress -c 2 -t 100`
- I've installed `apt-get install thinkfan`, but even after reboot `sudo systemctl status/enable/start thinkfan` outputs *Unit thinkfan.service not found*
- I've edited `/etc/thinkfan.conf.` to uncomment:
  tp_fan /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
  tp_thermal /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal (0, 10, 15, 2, 10, 5, 0, 3, 0, 3)
- However, I'm able to start thinkfan: `sudo thinkfan -n` in non-daemon mode. Fan started to start when I run stress. I've ended that run, it wrote *cleaning up and resetting fan control*
- After that I've started `sudo thinkfan` - `Daemon PID: 2548`, then `kill 2548`.
- I might have started thinkfan a couple of times as above.
- Now (there are no thinkfan processes seen in System Monitor), after I do `echo level 0 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan`, I can see `cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan`: `disabled, 0, 0`, but after I do `stress -c 2 -t 100` after about 10 seconds I start to hear fan noise and `cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan`: `enabled, 5578, auto`.
- By the way, `/proc/acpi/ibm/thermal` gives output of about 40 as the first number when idle and ~80 when stress starts (the other numbers stay the same).

Initial issue (just in case):

Started thinkfan after install by (as far as can recall) `sudo systemctl enable thinkfan`. Wanted to go manually temporary and tried `stop`, `disable`: `sudo systemctl disable thinkfan`, there is no process called `thinkfan` running, output of `sudo systemctl status thinkfan`:

```
● thinkfan.service - simple and lightweight fan control program
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/thinkfan.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-11-11 18:09:56 MSK; 2 days ago
   Main PID: 33742 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 11 18:09:51 alex-ThinkPad-slim thinkfan[33742]: A sensor has vanished! Exiting since there's no safe way of handling this.
Nov 11 18:09:56 alex-ThinkPad-slim thinkfan[33742]: Cleaning up and resetting fan control.
Nov 11 18:09:56 alex-ThinkPad-slim systemd[1]: thinkfan.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 11 18:09:56 alex-ThinkPad-slim systemd[1]: thinkfan.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 12 05:32:53 alex-ThinkPad-slim systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/thinkfan.service:9: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/thinkfan.pid → /run/thinkfan.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
```

However, fan starts by itself after being manually turned off -- why?

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
status:     disabled

$ stress -c 2 -t 100

$ cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
status:     enabled
```

Comment: the motherboard may have a hardware override that prevents errant software from destroying the motherboard

Comment: @jsotola, the point is that before thinkfan install writing level 0 disabled fan until restart/sleep events as far as I recall. There is a throttling feature against overheating.

Comment: @Nate, output IMO did not add much `thinkfan.service                                                                          loaded failed     failed    simple and lightweight fan control program`

Comment: @Nate than the question is "what starts the fan?"

Comment: @Nate, what do you mean by " sry multitasking. "? BTW I've finished the example, it reproduces the issue.

Comment: Aha! You were changing the question. I was confused earlier because when I looked back at the question, I thought I'd missed info. I think we were both adding at the same time. I was reading / responding to your Q in one monitor while programming in another. That is what I meant. My concentration was /is spread thin, so I thought I had looked over the last half of your question somehow. BTW, Ill probably delete these comments once you've seen them so as not to distract from the question. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Could the thinkfan service be resetting the configuration while trying to set its environment, before it fails. The fact that it says `failed ` in the systemctl output means that it has to be at least attempting to run. To test, you could try unloading the module with `modprobe` and see if it still resets.

Comment: May this is the similar like your problem: https://github.com/vmatare/thinkfan/issues/36

Answer (score 2):

Ah, bounty wasted (maybe not if somebody will write a better, more comprehensive answer).

I've found in `thinkfan` (at least 0.9) [code](https://github.com/vmatare/thinkfan) (as I've understood it) activation of `watchdog` for fan control. `echo watchdog 0 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan` disables it so needed in addition to `echo disable | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan` to revert changes made by `thinkfan`.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/laptops/thinkpad-acpi.rst:

> The thinkpad-acpi kernel driver can be programmed to revert the fan
> level to a safe setting if userspace does not issue one of the procfs
> fan commands: "enable", "disable", "level" or "watchdog", or if there
> are no writes to pwm1_enable (or to pwm1 *if and only if* pwm1_enable
> is set to 1, manual mode) within a configurable amount of time of up
> to 120 seconds.  This functionality is called fan safety watchdog.
>
> Note that the watchdog timer stops after it enables the fan.  It will
> be rearmed again automatically (using the same interval) when one of
> the above mentioned fan commands is received.  The fan watchdog is,
> therefore, not suitable to protect against fan mode changes made
> through means other than the "enable", "disable", and "level" procfs
> fan commands, or the hwmon fan control sysfs interface.

> To program the safety watchdog, use the "watchdog" command::
>
> echo 'watchdog ' > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
>
> If you want to disable the watchdog, use 0 as the interval.