# Writing to procfs file opened with r+ does not change modification timestamp (as opposed to opened with w) - any particular reason?

Tags: linux, proc

Noted for a file in `/proc` modification timestamp is not changed when file is written to after being open in `r+` mode (but changed if opened in `w` mode). Any particular reason why is it working that way?

TL;DR

When tackling an issue with thinkfan ([Why fan gets enabled again and again after thinkfan started and ended once?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677382/why-fan-gets-enabled-again-and-again-after-thinkfan-started-and-ended-once)), noted that `/proc/acpi/ibm/fan` modification time is not changed as a result of `thinkfan` operation, I doubted the program uses it. But building modified code myself confirmed it opens it, `((fan = fopen(IBM_FAN, "r+")) == NULL)`. I opened the file in my `c` app with `w`, when I've changed my code to open with `r+` timestamp of modification also stopped to change.

Just doing `echo level 1 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan` also update file modification timestamp. I've read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113919/difference-between-r-and-w-in-fopen and the difference `r+` and `w` is that `w` truncates the file. Just in case checked on `ext4` writing to file opened with `r+` updates modification timestamp.

Added per comments:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
status:     disabled
speed:      0
level:      0
commands:   level <level> (<level> is 0-7, auto, disengaged, full-speed)
commands:   enable, disable
commands:   watchdog <timeout> (<timeout> is 0 (off), 1-120 (seconds))


$ sudo strace stopfan // r+
execve("/usr/local/bin/stopfan", ["stopfan"], 0x7ffdf26fdc50 /* 25 vars */) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/acpi/ibm/fan", O_RDWR) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
write(3, "level 0\n", 8)                = 8
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++

$ sudo strace ./stopfan // w+
execve("./stopfan", ["./stopfan"], 0x7ffca68b2d40 /* 25 vars */) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/acpi/ibm/fan", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
write(3, "level 0\n", 8)                = 8
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: What is the file content before and after the operation? Can you add the strace output for opening, writing to, and closing that file?

Comment: @Hauke, content? this is zero length file per `ls`. I'm not sure how to add strace properly, the app is run with set-user-ID as root fine, but when I've tried `strace my_app` I saw output indicating it was not run as root. Therefore I've added `sudo strace my_app`

Comment: The file sizes in `/proc` are determined on reading the files so they are not shown correctly in directory listings. Just do `(sudo) cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan`. You need to run strace as root: `sudo strace my_app`

Comment: @Hauke, added cat and strace

Comment: I guess the strace output is for the `fopen(IBM_FAN, "w"))` version. I have restricted the output to the interesting part. Of course, we need the outputs for both versions. I just realize that I do not know which component is responsible for mtimes in `/proc`. That may be the kernel but also the affected driver/module.

Comment: @Hauke, output(s) of r+ and w+ do not look much different IMO (stopfan is my app, I do about same: fopen, fprintf, fclose).

Comment: I just did `ls -l /proc` and all the files there had mtime set to the current time. I doubt `proc` even tries to be consistent in any way with the times. It also seems to never update atime. The only place I can see mtime mentioned in the source (in `fs/proc`) is a few places that do `inode->i_mtime = inode->i_atime = inode->i_ctime = current_time(inode)`. Maybe the update seen on rewrite comes from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whether this is intentional or a bug (maybe useful to ask on the kernel mailing list if noone here explains it).

But I can confirm that this seems to be a general behaviour in `/proc`. I tried it with `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`. `echo 0 >>ip_forward` does change the value from `1` to `0` but does not change mtime. `echo 1 >ip_forward` does change mtime.